# Why is NuGet looking at global cache but hintpath points to ..\packages

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

My project's .csproj file has hintpaths for packages set to ..\packages\etc...

NuGet says all packages are available as I have the packages in my global cache under C:\Users\\AppData\NuGet Packages\packages

Each package in the references folder has a yellow warning sign as there is no ..\packages folder.

I can move the packages from the global cache and manually create the ..\packages folder or point the hintpaths to the global cache folder to get the project running, but then my builds fail in CI/CD.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 15.5.5, NuGet Package Manager 4.5.0

The error message:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
>   computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
>   missing file is
>   ..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props.

Why isn't NuGet trying to create the ..\packages folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my NuGet.config there was a setting:

```
<add key="repositoryPath" value="..\..\NuGet Packages\packages" />
```

No idea why that was there. Once I removed this everything went back to normal creating a solution level packages folder